# Is it good practice for a class to implement itself in a generic interface?

Tags: java, generics

Apologies for the question title, I couldn't put this into words easily.

I've just come across this in some code:

```
public class MyClass implements Message<MyClass> {...}
```

I understand what it does but I've never seen a class declared in this way before.

The disadvantage I see is that now `MyClass` is a Message and needs to include implemented methods that are unrelated to its primary purpose.

One advantage I see (other than it reduces the number of other classes I would otherwise need to write) is that for things like `Comparable`, `MyClass` would know how to compare itself to other instance, which in turn would make for more concise code.

Is this good practice? Are there any rules-of-thumb?

Comment: Check out the `Enum` class from the standard library. Each `enum` does just that, and serves as an example of why it makes sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is more or less the only way in Java to have an interface with methods that refer to the implementing class itself.  So, for example, you might write a binary tree node interface:

```
interface TreeNode<N extends TreeNode<N>> {
  N getLeftChild();
  N getRightChild();
  void setLeftChild(N node);
  void setRightChild(N node);
}
```

and then you have classes like

```
class TreeNodeWithInt extends TreeNode<TreeNodeWithInt> {
  int value;
  TreeNodeWithInt leftChild;
  TreeNodeWithInt rightChild;
  public TreeNodeWithInt getLeftChild() { return leftChild; }
  public void setLeftChild(TreeNodeWithInt newLeft) { leftChild = newLeft; }
  ...
}
```

If we didn't have the `N` type parameter, you would be forced to write unsafe code like

```
class TreeNodeWithInt extends TreeNode {
  int value;
  TreeNodeWithInt leftChild;
  TreeNodeWithInt rightChild;

  public void setLeftChild(TreeNode node) {
    // note the dangerous cast!
    leftChild = (TreeNodeWithInt) node;
  }
}
```

The key issue here is that interfaces aren't allowed to refer to the type of the class that's implementing the interface, when they describe the input and return types of methods. So instead, you include a "self" generic type parameter.  It's a relatively common idiom in code that makes extensive use of generics.

As you've correctly identified, it's frequently used with `Comparable` specifically, because you *should* only be able to compare objects to other objects of the same type.  Indeed, `Collections.sort` is specified to take a `List<T>` where `T extends Comparable<? super T>`, which means that `T` is comparable to at *least* other values of type `T`, but possibly others as well.

(Finally, as you might expect -- since it's the only way to achieve this behavior, it's not "good" or "bad" practice.  That said, the goal of the technique is to avoid writing methods that compile without warnings but can end up throwing `ClassCastException`, which is itself a good practice.)

Comment: Note that if your TreeNode stored reference types, it would probably be better to just make `N` refer to the data type (i.e. don't have it extend `TreeNode<N>`) and have get/setChild return/accept a `TreeNode<N>`.  This example makes sense mainly because you're using `int` as the value type which can't be used in a generic instantiation.

Comment: Eh.  I've encountered instances in the wild where I wanted tree nodes to carry more metadata than just a single field -- total subtree size, for example -- in which this technique was fully necessary.

Comment: `interface TreeNode<N>` is sufficient. `interface TreeNode<N extends TreeNode<N>>` really doesn't add any benefit

Comment: Mmmmm, it adds some benefit.  You want to force all your _users_ to have a generic type parameter `N extends TreeNode<N>`, and `TreeNode<N extends TreeNode<N>>` makes it so anything less won't compile.

Comment: In my experience, this approach works well for simple hierarchies. As soon as multiple-inheritance is involved you are better off replacing it with (1) object composition or (2) unrestricted type-parameters. Approach 1 is safe, easy-to-understand, but requires more work every time the base class is modified. This extra work is not wasted. In my experience, forcing sub-classes to make an explicit decision as to whether they want to delegate via composition or provide their own implementation reduces design mistakes.

Comment: Approach 2 is prone to runtime errors but in practice this is extremely unlikely to cause problems so long as your unit tests hit at least one method that use self-types, per class.

Answer (score 1):

It is neither "good practice" or "bad practice".

The real question is whether it accurately models what you are trying to achieve.  In some cases it will, in others it won't.

And if a particular use of the "meta-pattern" results in unwanted and / or meaningless methods, then you have a strong case that it is not the right solution.

> Are there any rules-of-thumb?

If it doesn't work in a particular use-case, don't use it in that use-case :-)

Answer (score 0):

While my example is phrased in C#, it translates to Java, and makes sense as a useful idiom for doing common tasks for the class, especially for domain classes. That said, it's neither good nor bad practice.

```
class Product :  IEquatable<Product>, ICloneable<Product>, IComparable<Product>
```

or in Java

```
class Product implements IEquatable<Product>, ICloneable<Product>, IComparable<Product>
```

In this example, I can define a product that knows how to check itself for equality with another, clone itself (perhaps in a generic reusable way), compare itself and so on.

I often use something like the above with code generation, putting as much of the generic at the root level as possible, and extending the more specific things at leaf levels.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, and as Stephen C mentioned, this is neither a good or bad practice. In fact, I your description is not really accurate. This is not a case of a class implementing itself, but a class saying that it is the parameter for the parameterized interface it wants to implement.

```
public class MyClass implements Message<MyClass> {...}
```

This effectively means that Message is a "parameterized" interface, meaning, the interface itself accepts a parameter. In this case, the parameter just happens to be the same class that is implementing the parameterized class. But it could be something else. Imagine this:

```
public class UserDAO implements DAO<User> {...}
```